# How to say "historical reenactment" in Russian?

Tags: выбор-слова

How to say "historical reenactment" in Russian? For example, when talking about some festival with a historical reenactment of some medieval battle.

EDIT:
"историческая реконструкция", as far as I can tell, has three meanings. One is like a process of recovery of some facts, and another one is like a wall with pictures. But what I want is precisely a term that would convey only one meaning, that is the third meaning, which is a kind of performance or a cosplay.

Comment: An English Wikipedia article on historical reenactment had a Russian counterpart and thus, translation can easily obtained. As it can be through dictionaries. You can try to edit your question so that it will be on-topic, however translations without prior effort to come up with the right answer are off-topic.

Comment: @shabunc - The problem is that the translation provided on the Russian page can be easily interpreted in other ways. One is like a process of recovery of some facts, and another one is like a wall with pictures. But what I want is precisely a term that would convey only one meaning, that is the third meaning, which is a kind of performance.

Comment: Can you please edit your question adding exactly this concerns - it will make question on-topic

Comment: @shabunc - Does my mention of a festival not suffice?

Comment: Well as you can see from the answer already provided it's not clear enough

Comment: @shabunc - I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia on [Историческая реконструкция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

If the collocation refers not to the cosplay culture, where reenactment is the goal in itself, but to a one-off show within another event, then these could work

> Инсценировка исторического события
>
> Театрализованное воссоздание исторического события

Answer (score 8):

"историческая реконструкция" is the proper term for historical reenactment.

Comment: But will it not be taken in a physical sense? I mean, like a stand with pictures on it, while what I mean is actual people performing, dressed in historical costumes.

Comment: @brilliant it's an established term and context tells you what exactly it denotes in each case, but if it comes to the pinch one can simply ask for clarification

Comment: People who go in for it call it реконструкция and name themselves реконструкторы and, informally, реконы. So, it is a common term.

Answer (score 0):

**[Ролевые игры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)** (live action role-playing game). And a players are called **"[Ролевики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8)"**

If "историческая реконструкция" has more official context and use mainly in science, "Ролевые игры" is like a hobby and improvisation, and including historical reenactment, cosplay, minstrel, tolkiens, historical dancing and etc.

Here is an [example](http://volk.nn.ru/about) of festival

> "ВолК" - это ... ежегодный фестиваль ролевых игр.

Comment: I am afraid that "ролевые игры" has too much of sporting connotation while what I mean is more of a performance to be watched. Do you think "театрализованное воспроизведение исторических событий" would fit the bill?

Comment: @brilliant yes it would, and suggestions in my answer